# "Not doing so" vs "doing so" after a negative

Tags: phrase-choice, adverbial-phrases

Which is the proper phrase to follow a negative declaration? For example:

> I will never go, even if [not doing so/doing so] means death.

Which of the two would be the correct to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky to parse, but only the former makes sense for what you appear to be trying to say. "Even if **not going** [not doing so] means death, I will **not go**, ever" is the sense of it.

I strongly recommend you rephrase, though, since when I first read it I misunderstood what you were saying and almost wrote the answer wrong! Suggestion:

> I will never go, even if it costs my death.

Or perhaps (using an idiom):

> I will go only over my own dead body.

Comment: "I will never go, even if it costs my life," might make more sense. :)

Comment: @Nahom: Oddly, either works, and they mean the same thing.